# Using python3 and connected to sqlite3 I want to display tables that are in my database, "." in ".tables" keeps giving error and "\" is not helpful

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect("vsearchlogDB.db")
print("Opened database successfully")  
cursor = connection.cursor()
_SQL = """.tables"""
cursor.execute(_SQL)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Output

```
>>>python3 dbconnect.py 
Opened database successfully
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/amrit/Documents/webapp/dbconnect.py", line 6, in <module>
cursor.execute(_SQL)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the "." from _sql because you are executing a sql command which does not accept "."